# Office Addin not working in Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office-js, adal, office-addins

I created an Office addin that I'm trying to submit to the store, but I'm being rejected because the addin needs to work in Office 2013. I'm using ADAL 1.0.13 to Authenticate to both Microsoft Graph and my app that is hosted on AD.

For some reason when I login into 365 from Office 2013 I can't get a token for Microsoft Graph, but I do get it for my app.

When I check localstorage there is no access token for graph

```
adal.token.renew.status5367d787-ea68-4352-a336-99d69dabc81d: Completed 
adal.token.renew.statushttps://graph.microsoft.com: In Progress
```

The addin works for every office platform Office365, Office 2016, IOS, MAC, except Office 2013.

Any thoughts would definitely help.

Thank you

Here is my ADAL Log

> Thu, 04 May 2017 18:50:07 GMT:1.0.13-VERBOSE: Location change event from https://wd365.azurewebsites.net/ to https://wd365.azurewebsites.net/
>
> Thu, 04 May 2017 18:50:07 GMT:1.0.13-VERBOSE: Location change event from https://wd365.azurewebsites.net/ to https://wd365.azurewebsites.net/#/user
>
> Thu, 04 May 2017 18:50:07 GMT:1.0.13-VERBOSE: Url: /views/user.html maps to resource: null
>
> Thu, 04 May 2017 18:50:07 GMT:1.0.13-VERBOSE: Url: /apiServer maps to resource: 5367d787-ea68-4352-a336-99d69dabc81d
>
> Thu, 04 May 2017 18:50:07 GMT:1.0.13-INFO: Token is available for this url /apiServer
>
> Thu, 04 May 2017 18:50:07 GMT:1.0.13-VERBOSE: Url: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me maps to resource: https://graph.microsoft.com
>
> Thu, 04 May 2017 18:50:07 GMT:1.0.13-INFO: renewToken is called for resource:https://graph.microsoft.com
>
> Thu, 04 May 2017 18:50:07 GMT:1.0.13-INFO: Add adal frame to document:adalRenewFramehttps://graph.microsoft.com
>
> Thu, 04 May 2017 18:50:07 GMT:1.0.13-VERBOSE: Renew token Expected state: a3ad9e34-cbd9-4e79-84f9-6065edd6b335|https://graph.microsoft.com
>
> Thu, 04 May 2017 18:50:07 GMT:1.0.13-INFO: Navigate url:https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=5367d787-ea68-4352-a336-99d69dabc81d&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwd365.azurewebsites.net%2F&state=a3ad9e34-cbd9-4e79-84f9-6065edd6b335%7Chttps%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com&client-request-id=0d76a714-62c9-45ca-af04-f548dd658f63&x-client-SKU=Js&x-client-Ver=1.0.13
>
> Thu, 04 May 2017 18:50:07 GMT:1.0.13-VERBOSE: Navigate to:https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=5367d787-ea68-4352-a336-99d69dabc81d&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwd365.azurewebsites.net%2F&state=a3ad9e34-cbd9-4e79-84f9-6065edd6b335%7Chttps%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com&client-request-id=0d76a714-62c9-45ca-af04-f548dd658f63&x-client-SKU=Js&x-client-Ver=1.0.13&prompt=none&login_hint=oasmat%40worldox.com&domain_hint=worldox.com
>
> Thu, 04 May 2017 18:50:07 GMT:1.0.13-VERBOSE: Set loading state to pending for: https://graph.microsoft.com
>
> Thu, 04 May 2017 18:50:07 GMT:1.0.13-INFO: LoadFrame: adalRenewFramehttps://graph.microsoft.com
>
> Thu, 04 May 2017 18:50:08 GMT:1.0.13-INFO: Add adal frame to document:adalRenewFramehttps://graph.microsoft.com
>
> Thu, 04 May 2017 18:50:08 GMT:1.0.13-INFO: LoadFrame: adalRenewFramehttps://graph.microsoft.com
>
> Thu, 04 May 2017 18:50:08 GMT:1.0.13-INFO: Add adal frame to document:adalRenewFramehttps://graph.microsoft.com
>
> Thu, 04 May 2017 18:50:09 GMT:1.0.13-**ERROR**: Error when acquiring token for resource: https://graph.microsoft.com stack: undefined
>
> Thu, 04 May 2017 18:50:09 GMT:1.0.13-INFO: Getting error in the response: 
>   `{ "method":"GET",
>      "transformRequest":[null],
>      "transformResponse":[null],
>      "url":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me",
>      "headers": {"Accept":"application/json, text/plain,*/*"},
>      "data": "AADSTS50058: A silent sign-in request was sent but no user is
>               signed in. The cookies used to represent the user's session were
>               not sent in the request to Azure AD. This can happen if the user is
>               using Internet Explorer or Edge, and the web app sending the silent
>               sign-in request is in different IE security zone than the Azure AD
>               endpoint (login.microsoftonline.com).
>
>               Trace ID: 1cacf014-8aa1-4cb9-981d-a6addb0d1700
>               Correlation ID: 0d76a714-62c9-45ca-af04-f548dd658f63
>               Timestamp: 2017-05-04 18:50:12Z|login_required|undefined" }`

Here are my endpoint in my code

```
var azureADConfig = {
    clientId: "5367d787-ea68-4352-a336-99d69dabc81d",
    endpoints: {
        'https://graph.microsoft.com': 'https://graph.microsoft.com',
        'https://wdwebauth.azurewebsites.net': '5367d787-ea68-4352-a336-99d69dabc81d'
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, request was failed when it trying to renew the token silently.

Please ensure that you have sign-in the Azure AD before and the web browser doesn't block the cookies sending. Your web app should be in the same security zone as Azure AD endpoint(`login.microsoftonline.com`) on the machine which have this issue.

Comment: Xue do you have any documentation I can follow, how do you change security zone from my web app to match AD's endpoint? Is there a reason why this only happens on a computer running Office 2013 client on Windows 7 with IE11?

Comment: You can check the Security zone for a site by open this site in the IE, then we can check it via the Internet options->Security. It will locate the site to a specific zone. More detail about URL Security Zones, you can refer [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537183(v=vs.85).aspx#zones).